# Проблема с переносом файлом c github в idea ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

После переноса проекта в идею произошел сбой, в результате которого модуль patterns стал обычной дерикторией, а классы начали отображаться как обычные java файлы, из-за чего нет возможности работать с ними[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте удалить папку .idea, импортировать проект заново.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши по папке `src` -> `Mark directory as` -> `Source root`